# Convert a PXCImage into an OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, realsense

I'm working on the Intel's RealSense SDK. For signal processing purposes, I have to convert it into an OpenCV format.

Do you have a function to do such a conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the conversion (some cases aren't managed but feel free to adapt it):

```
void ConvertPXCImageToOpenCVMat(PXCImage *inImg, Mat *outImg) {
    int cvDataType;
    int cvDataWidth;


    PXCImage::ImageData data;
    inImg->AcquireAccess(PXCImage::ACCESS_READ, &data);
    PXCImage::ImageInfo imgInfo = inImg->QueryInfo();

    switch (data.format) {
        /* STREAM_TYPE_COLOR */
        case PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_YUY2: /* YUY2 image  */
        case PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_NV12: /* NV12 image */
            throw(0); // Not implemented
        case PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB32: /* BGRA layout on a little-endian machine */
            cvDataType = CV_8UC4;
            cvDataWidth = 4;
            break;
        case PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB24: /* BGR layout on a little-endian machine */
            cvDataType = CV_8UC3;
            cvDataWidth = 3;
            break;
        case PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_Y8:  /* 8-Bit Gray Image, or IR 8-bit */
            cvDataType = CV_8U;
            cvDataWidth = 1;
            break;

        /* STREAM_TYPE_DEPTH */
        case PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH: /* 16-bit unsigned integer with precision mm. */
        case PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_RAW: /* 16-bit unsigned integer with device specific precision (call device->QueryDepthUnit()) */
            cvDataType = CV_16U;
            cvDataWidth = 2;
            break;
        case PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_F32: /* 32-bit float-point with precision mm. */
            cvDataType = CV_32F;
            cvDataWidth = 4;
            break;

        /* STREAM_TYPE_IR */
        case PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_Y16:          /* 16-Bit Gray Image */
            cvDataType = CV_16U;
            cvDataWidth = 2;
            break;
        case PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_Y8_IR_RELATIVE:    /* Relative IR Image */
            cvDataType = CV_8U;
            cvDataWidth = 1;
            break;
        }

    // suppose that no other planes
    if (data.planes[1] != NULL) throw(0); // not implemented
    // suppose that no sub pixel padding needed
    if (data.pitches[0] % cvDataWidth!=0) throw(0); // not implemented

    outImg->create(imgInfo.height, data.pitches[0] / cvDataWidth, cvDataType);

    memcpy(outImg->data, data.planes[0], imgInfo.height*imgInfo.width*cvDataWidth*sizeof(pxcBYTE));

    inImg->ReleaseAccess(&data);
    }
```