# Convert a PXCImage into an OpenCV Mat (PIXEL_FORMAT_YUY2)

Tags: c++, opencv, realsense

I'm working on the Intel's RealSense SDK and I have to convert it into an OpenCV format.

I saw this solution in the forum ([Convert a PXCImage into an OpenCV Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609341/convert-a-pxcimage-into-an-opencv-mat)) but for the "PIXEL_FORMAT_YUY2" type doesn't work that code.

Anyone knows how to change it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Intel RealSense SDK as I have only used the [librealsense](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense) API.

The documentation for the Intel RealSense SDK shoud be [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/index.html?doc_devguide_whats_new_in_sdk.html).

I don't know how it works with the SDK but with `librealsense` you can select directly the appropriate color format (for OpenCV `mat` it should be `bgr8`).

If you don't have this option with the SDK, you can see [here](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/src/image.cpp#L109) how `librealsense` unpack `yuy2` format.

Or maybe you can try to copy the data directly to a `mat` (you will have to figure out the good value for `cvDataType` and the good value for `cvDataWidth`) and then use [`cvtColor()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) with the appropriate [conversion](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0) if you want to be able to access to the pixel values as a RGB triplet?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Maybe it's a silly question, but I don't know exactly how to install librealsense... I seen some commands for Ubuntu, but I didn't see any tutorial step by step for windows. Could you help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `librealsense` is the alternative for platforms other than Windows. For Windows, I think that Intel recommends to use the SDK. You can still build from source `librealsense` with CMake and Visual Studio. You should check the default color format you get with the SDK, maybe it is a format different than `yuy2` and you should be able to convert to `mat bgr` easily.

Comment: In the Intel SDK de format is PIXEL_FORMAT_YUY2, but I don't know how to do this conversion. I did this:   
 
 `colorIm->AcquireAccess(PXCImage::ACCESS_READ, PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_YUY2, &frmData);`

 `image_openCV = Mat(Size(640, 480), CV_8UC3, frmData.planes[0]);` 
  But it doesn't work well, the image is not sort correctly.

Comment: [Here](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/index.html?acquireaccess_pxcimage.html) you have an example and [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/pixelformat_pxcimage.html) the list of image formats. With `PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB24`, you should be able to get a `mat` image. You will need to swap the red with the blue channel as a `mat` image is in `BGR` format (see `cvtColor` in OpenCV).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works for the RGB image! Now I'm trying to do the same thing but with the depth image. I think I've prove all the possible format combinations, but I'm not be able to replicate it. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Not sure to understand. Maybe this? `sm->EnableStream(PXCCapture::STREAM_TYPE_DEPTH,640,480);` and after `PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH` or `PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_RAW`? Anyway, I don't have a Windows platform.